# How to describe meaning of R squared?

Tags: regression, interpretation

What is the correct interpretation of R squared? How do you typically write the results? Could I say something like

> Age explained 30% of variation of the car condition index.

Please help :)

Comment: Is age the only predictor in your model? Or did you have other variables in the model? Otherwise, this is the correct interpretation of R-squared!

Comment: Yes it is the only predictor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MattReichenbach said, if you have Age is the only predictor in your model, then your wording is fine. However, in order to avoid specifying a particular variable, I would suggest the following wording: "**the model** explains 30% of variation of the car condition index" (also note the use of present tense, which to me sounds more natural and correct). Using "the model" will allow you easier modification of results reporting (more flexibility) in the future, for example, in case, if/when you will add more predictors to the model.

Comment: Completely agree. Well said, @Aleksandr!

Comment: @MattReichenbach: I appreciate your kind words!